# Проблема с чтением сессии

Tags: apache, php, openserver

```
public function __authentication (){

    session_start();
    $_SESSION["login"] = $row["Login"];
    $_SESSION["password"] = $row["Password"];
    $_SESSION["name"] = $row["Name"];
    $_SESSION["uid"] = $row["UID"];
    $_SESSION["key"] = $row["key"];
   setcookie(session_name(),session_id(),time()+((3600*24)*7));
   header("location: ../Panel/list.php");
}

function f1(){
session_start();
echo $_SESSION["name"];   // выводит NULL
}
```

Учитывая то, что в временной папке с сессиями, есть данная сессия.
работаю с OpenServer.

PHP 5.5.6 
Apache 2.4

Comment: .

    setcookie(session_name(),session_id(),time()+((3600*24)*7));

Эта строчка не нужна вообще, хотя и не должна никак влиять. Но лучше убрать.

    $_SESSION["name"] = $row["Name"];

А откуда `$row` взялся-то?

Comment: 1) куки, как один из способов хранения идентификатора сессиию
2) $row, да там все нормально, значение есть.

Проблема вот в чем, в том же файле из соседней функции не могу считать Сессию. старт есть везде..

Comment: @Юра Сучко, кто вам сказал, что эту куку вручную надо выставлять?

> This function sends out several HTTP headers

(это как раз про куку, пр очто же еще)

http://php.net//manual/ru/function.session-start.php

> $row, да там все нормально,

Еще раз: здесь его нет, и пока мы фиксим один код, проблема лежит в другом. Текущее поведение как раз-таки указывает на то, что никакого $row нету, если он у вас существует снаружи метода - то у метода своя область видимости, куда он не попадает.

Comment: заместо $row было уже "1234", свой текст. Он тут как раз и не причем, просто не хочется выкладывать второстепенный код, который вообще не играет роли в этом деле. если там есть 2-5 функций, которые даже не вызываются, зачем их вылаживать

Comment: @Юра Сучко, я не могу разгадать то, чего не вижу. Что в этом примере не так - я написал.
Есть еще вероятность, что там какие-то ошибки, но они не отображаются из-за заголовка перенаправления.

Comment: Проблему нашел. Пробовал всё что мог, напоследок решил куки почистить, в итоге - помогло, и теперь работает отлично.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

session_start() - должна быть перед любыми заголовками отправленными с сервера.

```
<?php
    session_start();
```

Подробней о работе [сессий в php](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/session.idpassing.php)